# Using Doctrine Query builder to return dates based on a specific day of the week

Tags: doctrine-orm, query-builder

I have a table with a list of dates and I would like to rerun **n** dates greater than **x-date** and that fall on a **Tuesday**.

Here is the list:

```
2015:07:31 - Fri
2015:08:04 - Tue
2015:08:07 - Fri
2015:08:11 - Tue
2015:08:14 - Fri
2015:08:18 - Tue
2015:08:21 - Fri
2015:08:25 - Tue
2015:08:28 - Fri
2015:09:01 - Tue
2015:09:04 - Fri
2015:09:08 - Tue
2015:09:11 - Fri
2015:09:15 - Tue
2015:09:18 - Fri
2015:09:22 - Tue
2015:09:25 - Fri
2015:09:29 - Tue
2015:10:02 - Fri
2015:10:06 - Tue
```

The code that returns the above list is:

```
$days  = $this->repository->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->where( 'u.someId = :someObject' )
        ->andHaving( 'u.thisDate >= :x-date')
        ->setMaxResults($n)
        ->setParameter('x-date',$x-date)
        ->setParameter('someObject',$someObject)
        ->getQuery()
```

What do I need to update in my query to return the dates that fall on Tuesday exclusively?

Comment: Since DAYOFWEEK is not standard sql, Doctrine 2 requires an extension.  Here is an example: https://github.com/orocrm/doctrine-extensions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My requirement was a lot more complex than I first anticipated. I opted not to use an extension since there was very little benefit in the long run.

My steps are as follows:

1. Get data from tables
2. Remove unwanted rows
3. Validate each row
4. Return final result

Fortunately, this is not a regular call so it wont have a noticeable impact on the end user. However, I have earmarked the code for refactoring when I have a couple of minds to help me mull over a better way to design it.